# Elzevier Caps Regular (font)

Tags: fonts

I have found a [new and wonderful font](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/elzevier/). According to the website, "Elzevier Caps Regular is part of TeX Live". This is my Tex-verion:

```
root@basip:~# tex --version
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\usefont{T1}{fvm}{m}{n}}
\setkomafont{section}{\usefont{T1}{fvs}{b}{n}\Large}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\input Elzevier.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Elzevier}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Elzevier Caps Regular}
\subsection*{\textbackslash initfamily}
\normalfont\initfamily
\fontsize{12mm}{12mm}\selectfont THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE SLEAZY DOG
\newpage
\normalfont\initfamily
\input fonttable
\end{document}
```

And I got this errors:

```
! I can't find file `fonttable'.
l.21 \input fonttable
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
l.21 \input fonttable
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
2584 strings out of 493485
35205 string characters out of 3143527
112716 words of memory out of 3000000
5889 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
11399 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
38i,4n,47p,253b,139s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What to do? I think my TeX-live version is too old? Or is there another problem? And if it is the problem, how to update TeXlive on Debian Wheezy?

Kind regards!

Comment: Oh how I would want that font separated so that the different parts can be printed in different colors! :)

Comment: Simply remove the `\input fonttable` and add some text instead. Or use the fonttable package if you want to produce a table.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `fonttable.tex` file. You can use the `fonttable` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\pagestyle{empty}
\input Elzevier.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Elzevier}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}

\xfonttable{U}{Elzevier}{xl}{n}

\end{document}
```

[image]